# How do I remove poster image from video in pptx-python

Tags: python-pptx

So I am inserting videos using add_video function in pptx-python. The documentation says one of the inputs is a poster_image for the video. IF this is not set, it shows a huge speaker icon in the video. How do I remove the speaker and not have a poster_image?

```
def makevideoslide(prs,video,title1,layout):
video_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[layout]
#POSITION ON SLIDE
left = Inches(1.63)
top = Inches(1.24)
height = Inches(3.71)
width = Inches(6.78)
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(video_slide_layout) #Actualy making the slide 
title = slide.shapes.title #Title that goes on top of the layout and the slide
title.text = title1
vid = slide.shapes.add_movie(video, left, top, width=width,height=height,) 
return slide
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying a blank white image as the poster-image?

Comment: Thank you for your response! The problem is that I would just want the start of the video to be the cover image. I don't want it to be a white image or any image.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation here](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html?highlight=add_movie#pptx.shapes.shapetree.SlideShapes.add_movie):

> A poster frame image must be provided, **it cannot be automatically extracted from the video file**. If no poster frame is provided, the default “media loudspeaker” image will be used.

So you'll need to snap an image of the poster frame you want, perhaps by pausing the video and making a screen grab or with some software that allows you to select frames from the video, and provide that to the `.add_movie()` call.